# Wrong content div's heights on Bootstrap 3, for full screen page (no scrolling)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My page -> [tora.16mb.com](http://tora.16mb.com/) have problem with content div's heinght.
Index.php page looking good on screen but about or gallery section looking depend of screen resolution. Actualy I used stiff padding px value on dose pages. But I have no idea how to make this div's height, if I would like to see nav and footer is this same place (very bootom of screen) regardless of resolution?

Comment: Remove `overfolw:hidden;` from body it'll allow you to scroll. But rest of the question is unclear.

Comment: This page dont need scroll, must be fit to screen

Comment: http://s16.postimg.org/eslexnjet/rwd.png

Black div need to have height who make page will be fit to screen on any resolutions